# Back propagation to find the value of z

Tags: machine-learning, backpropagation

I hope all of you are doing well. I am a high school student, studying machine learning for my interest.I am studying the Backpropagation Algorithm in recent days. I got stuck in a problem:

[image]

After the forward pass,  the value of the terminating variable (green) is 1400 (I found it) but I can't find the value of the derivative at z, If backpropagation is run, beginning with the terminating variable in the graph.

To my knowledge, I have to set the weight and biases in such a way that the value of z will be minimum. I need to define a function through gradient ( mainly partial derivative).

- Initial values of w and b are randomly chosen.
- Epsilon (e) is the learning rate. It determines the gradient’s influence. w and b are matrix representations of the weights and biases. Derivative of C in w or b can be calculated using partial derivatives of C in the individual weights or biases.
- The termination condition is met once the cost function is minimized.

Or, **I will define some name to the intermediate node, Like w1,w2; then, I will get f(x,y) = a linear combination of W1,w2 with automatic differentiation.**

I stuck on creating the function for it as It looks like a new graph rather than a neural network graph where the algorithm is used. If someone explains to me the way to approach with the solution, I hope I can solve this type of problem easily.

Thank you so much.

Comment: Did you ever end up solving the derivative at z? I am also stuck on this question.